Redacted Text + Screen Reader best practice
I am seeking guidance on how to best handle the concept of redacted text. Since I work for the government, we typically have to post content online in both web and pdf formats that might contain redacted text. We remove the actual text so bad actors can not pull the actual redactions out, but when a screen reader hits one of these elements, what would be the best practice? I find the Adobe read-aloud skips to the next visible word. Should this be handled similarly to an inline image where the alt text should be used to indicate something has been there but was intentionally removed?

if this is HTML, could you maybe do something like
<p>
Lorem Ipsum <span aria-label="redacted" style="width: 5ch; height: 1em; background: black; display: inline-block;"></span> sit amet consectitor
<p>

and then style the span how you want to convey that same info to sighted users? eg give it a black background so sighted users see the recognizable black bar and SR users hear "redacted"
in a quick test, it does announce the span as an "empty group"

Why not add "redacted" to the  and style it:
`
Lorem Ipsum redacted sit amet consectitor
`  
That should also get rid of any "empty" announcements.

I thought about that, but wonder if that gets you in trouble for contrast reasons. At the very least it would be a false positive headache. But I agree it seems like an acceptable exception for contrast rules given its use and meaning in the context of the doc
